# convert list to text items in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an app that has a list of items. My customer prefers to edit the list in normal text.

So I want to find a way to transform the list items into text and vice-versa. What would you suggest?

edit: 
The items can be something like:

- John Doe, manager
- Jane Doe, manager
- Janine Doe, sales

But the customer wants to transform this list in pure text so he could for instance copy all and paste it to look like this:

- John Doe, manager
- Jane Doe, manager
- Janine Doe, sales
- John Doe, manager
- Jane Doe, manager
- Janine Doe, sales

This is an example, there are many scenarios.

Thank you

Comment: By transform do you mean copy+paste? You can subscribe to the copy event I believe for some WPF controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heavy weight solution - [DataGrid](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-datagrid-feature-walkthrough.aspx) from [WPF Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf).

Light weight - your own ListBox with custom ItemTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

What is there inside your items? You would need to add a `DataTemplate` for your item type, binding the visual elements to the properties of your items.